# Theory of steady state error and dynamics of error for automatic control systems

Tags: control-engineering, control-theory, pid-control

I'm currently studying control systems specifically the mass-spring-damper system.

[image]

Which is described by:

$$\ddot{y}=(b/m)\dot{y}+(k/m){y}=(b/m)\dot{u}+(k/m){u}$$
Where

$b:$ coeffiecient of friction

$k:$ coefficient of stiffnes

$m:$ mass of spring

From class we were told that 
$$error = e(t) =y_{ref}-y(t)$$
Taking the first and second derivative
$$\dot{e}(t)=-\dot{y(t)} $$
$$\ddot{e}(t)=-\ddot{y(t)}$$
After this we substituted with $e(t)$ 
$$\ddot{e}(t)=-(b/m)\dot{e}(t)-(k/m){e}(t)+r(t)+d/m$$

Then $r(t)$ is defined as $r(t)= ky_{ref}+mk_pe(t)$

What I don't understand is where does the term $r(t)$ and $d$ come from. The example is taken from Ogata's book, but the dynamics of the error isn't covered in the example of the boook. Where can I read more about this so I can understand this equation.

Comment: I voted to reject a suggested edit by @BarbalatsDilemma which modified equations on this question to "correct" them. If that was an attempt to answer the question, it should be posted as an answer. If that is an alias for the the question's author, Yudop, please get in touch with a moderator to merge your accounts.

Comment: Thanks for the update, and no I don't have another account besides this one.

Comment: @Wasabi Good point about the edit, I was assuming that the diagram was correct and that the equations were a typo. I will try to add an answer later. Btw I am not an alias for Yudop